# Use toLocaleLowerCase method with local parameter on Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a question about [String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) ;

I want to use toLocaleLowerCase() with locale parameter like [here](https://github.com/tc39/test262/blob/master/test/intl402/String/prototype/toLocaleLowerCase/special_casing_Turkish.js)

But I get this error.

[image: But I get this error]

lib.es5.d.ts

[image: lib.es5.d.ts]

Could you help me, please?

Package and System Info:

cli packages: (C:\Users\Ahmet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0-201710070411
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Node : v8.7.0
npm  : 5.5.1
OS   : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `locale` parameter is still in draft mode : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase

[image]

## Hot fix:

Use a type assertion ([beware](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)):

```
('some string' as any).toLocaleLowerCase('tr');
```

## Proper fix

Wait till the feature is standardized as it probably doesn't work across browsers right now.

Comment: Is this still in draft mode, link says all  browsers support it but I still get the same error when I add locale parameter, even type definition says it takes an optional parameter but compile fails